# What is a way to filter multiple values using .filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[7, 0, '', false, "words"]
```

I want to be able to filter out false, 0, and ' '. What is a good way to filter all of them out?

Comment: so add a couple of checks.... The or operator is your friend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `0`, `false` and  `''` are falsy values, you can use following method:

`v` is an argument for the `Array#filter` function. We are filtering every `truthy` value and passing it to the `result` variable. `Falsy` values - `[0, false, '']` won't be filtered (passed). The original array is not being mutated (changed).

```js
var result = [7, 0, '', false, "words"].filter(v => v);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is v doing in the filter method?

Comment: It’s just a function argument. It stands for each element.

Comment: @Xufox Please explain what means operator `v => v`

Comment: It is ES6 Syntx. Same thing as `function(v){ return v;}`

Answer (score 0):

You also can put callback to filter function

```js
var result = [7, 0, '', false, "words"].filter(function(e){
     return e != '' 
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @epascarello and what is wrong? Run code snippet and see result